# Sql-find duplicate values of two columns and display all values of "column 1" and unique value of "column 2"

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Data:(I have table data like below)

#### Column 1   | column 2     | column 3

---

1001        |     **50**       |    Id1

2001        |     **75**       |    Id2

1001        |     **50**      |    Id3

1501        |     25       |    Id4

2001        |     **75**      |    Id5

2003        |     75      |    Id5

2002        |     43      |    Id5

OutPut:(I need output like below using sql query)

#### Column 1 | column 2  |  column 3

---

1001     |   **50**      |      Id1

1001     |   **-**       |      Id3 ----(Replace Zero)

2001     |   **75**    |      Id2

2001     |     **-**         |      Id5 ----(Replace Zero)

1501     |   25      |      Id4

2003        |     75      |    Id5

2002        |     43      |    Id5

Comment: So what's the real goal? I imagine you are going to do something after this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT Column1,
       CASE WHEN LAG(Column2) OVER (PARTITION BY Column1 ORDER BY Column1) = Column2
            THEN ''
            ELSE Column2
       END AS Column2,
       Column3
FROM   YourTable
```